# Simple day-of-week program

Tags: python, beginner, datetime

I was doing the following exercise:

> Create an algorithm which asks the user a number from 1 to 7, and each number represents a day on the week. For example, 1 represents Sunday, 2 represents Monday and so on. The user will type this number and the program will show them the name of the day on the week and if it's a business day or a weekend.

I tried to do it in a object-oriented way and using Python. Can someone please verify if my code is within the Python and object-oriented "standards"? Because I'm not sure whether it is, and I need a review.

Here's my code:

```
class DayOnWeek:
    ERROR_MESSAGE = 'Invalid weekday. Try again:'
    NUMBER_NAME_ASSOCIATIONS = {
        1: 'Sunday',
        2: 'Monday',
        3: 'Tuesday',
        4: 'Wednesday',
        5: 'Thursday',
        6: 'Friday',
        7: 'Saturday'
    }

    def __init__(self):
        self._day_number = 0
        self._day_name = None
        self._category = None

    @property
    def day_name(self):
        return self._day_name

    @property
    def category(self):
        return self._category

    @property
    def day_number(self):
        return self._day_number

    @day_number.setter
    def day_number(self, value):
        if 1 <= value <= 7:
            self._day_number = value
            self._day_name = DayOnWeek.NUMBER_NAME_ASSOCIATIONS[self._day_number]
        else:
            raise ValueError(DayOnWeek.ERROR_MESSAGE)

        if 2 <= value <= 6:
            self._category = 'Business day'
        else:
            self._category = 'Weekend'


class DayOnWeekInterface:

    def __init__(self):
        self._day_on_week = DayOnWeek()

    def request_day_number(self):
        while True:
            try:
                day_num = input('Type the number of the day on the week (ex: 1 - Sunday):')
                day_num = int(day_num)
                self._day_on_week.day_number = day_num
                break
            except ValueError:
                print(DayOnWeek.ERROR_MESSAGE)
        self.show_day_on_week()

    def show_day_on_week(self):
        day_num = self._day_on_week.day_number
        day_name = self._day_on_week.day_name
        day_category = self._day_on_week.category
        print(f'The day {day_num} is {day_name.lower()}')
        print(f'{day_name} is a {day_category.lower()}')


DayOnWeekInterface().request_day_number()
```

Answer (score 10):

Your `DayOnWeek` object is mutable, allowing you to set the `.day_number` property.  For such a simple object is not a good idea.  An immutable object is better.

There are exactly 7 days of the week.  For a one-of-seven choice, the go-to data-storage structure is an [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).  For example:

```py
from enum import Enum

class DayOfWeek(Enum):
    Sunday = 1
    Monday = 2
    Tuesday = 3
    Wednesday = 4
    Thursday = 5
    Friday = 6
    Saturday = 7

    @property
    def weekend(self):
        return self in {DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday}

    @property
    def category(self):
        return 'Weekend' if self.weekend else 'Business day'

    @property
    def number(self):
        return self.value
```

Borrowing Reideerien's `request_day_number()` function you'd use the `DayOfWeek` enum like:

```py
def main():
    day_no = request_day_number()
    day = DayOfWeek(day_no)

    print(f'Day {day.number} is {day.name}')
    print(f'{day.name} is a {day.category} day')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi AJNeufeld. You have provided an alternate solution. However, answers must make at least one [insightful observation](/help/how-to-answer), and must explain why the change is better than the OP's code. Failure to follow the IO rule can result in your answer being deleted.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Does not "_Your DayOnWeek object is mutable, allowing you to set the .day_number property. For such a simple object [this] is not a good idea. An immutable object is better._" qualify as an insightful observation?

Answer (score 9):

It's great that you're thinking about classes, but you've misapplied them. This is a very simple problem that does not call for object-oriented code. The `calendar` module already has the name sequence, so you really only need a validation loop and a small output routine:

```
from calendar import day_name


def request_day_number() -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input(
                'Type the number of the day on the week (ex: 1 - Sunday): '
            ))
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid integer. Please try again.')
            continue

        if 1 <= value <= 7:
            return value
        print('Invalid weekday. Please try again.')


def main():
    day_no = request_day_number()
    name = day_name[day_no - 1]
    print(f'Day {day_no} is {name}')

    if 2 <= day_no <= 6:
        kind = 'business'
    else:
        kind = 'weekend'
    print(f'{name} is a {kind} day')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you were married to the idea of an object-oriented representation, here is one relatively sane (if somewhat overbuilt) way:

```
from calendar import day_name


class Weekday:
    def __init__(self, index: int):
        self.index = index
        if not (0 <= index < 7):
            raise ValueError(f'{self.one_based} is an invalid week day index')

    @property
    def one_based(self) -> int:
        return self.index + 1

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return day_name[self.index]

    @property
    def category(self) -> str:
        if self.index in {0, 6}:
            return 'weekend'
        return 'business'

    @classmethod
    def from_stdin(cls) -> 'Weekday':
        while True:
            try:
                value = int(input(
                    'Type the number of the day on the week (ex: 1 - Sunday): '
                ))
                return cls(value - 1)
            except ValueError as e:
                print(f'Invalid input: {e}. Please try again.')

    @property
    def description(self) -> str:
        return (
            f'Day {self.one_based} is {self}\n'
            f'{self} is a {self.category} day\n'
        )


def main():
    day = Weekday.from_stdin()
    print(day.description)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5):

There's some issues:

- when a new instance of your class is initialised, it has a state that's not supported by the rest of the code (i.e. a `_day_number` of `0`, with no matching name)
- The name `DayOnWeek` isn't very descriptive, why not just `Weekday`?
- Why not implement the `category` property as a property that decides the category based on the value of `_day_number` instead of storing the category in a hidden variable? (which is initialised to `None` as well, causing further problems)
- Similarly, why set `_day_name` to the name from the internal constant dictionary, instead of just returning the name directly from that in the property?
- The error message in the `DayOnWeek` class is specific to functionality in the `DayOnWeekInterface`, it should live there, or it should be phrased correctly.
- "Saturday is a Weekend"?
- You've created `DayOnWeekInterface` to separate out the interaction with the user, that's OK, but not a very common way to go about it, what exactly is the idea here?
- You've implemented a bunch of stuff that's just duplicating what existing libraries can do; not a great idea, unless you're coding this as a homework assignment that explicitly asks you to do so.
- All the properties and attributes have `_day` in their names, while they really are all directly applying to a `Day` object anyway, better naming would be simpler.

However, following the general design you chose, this would be a revised version without those issues:

```
class Weekday:
    ERROR_INVALID_NUMBER = 'Invalid day number.'

    DAY_NAMES = {
        1: 'Sunday',
        2: 'Monday',
        3: 'Tuesday',
        4: 'Wednesday',
        5: 'Thursday',
        6: 'Friday',
        7: 'Saturday'
    }

    def __init__(self, number=1):
        self.number = number

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.DAY_NAMES[self._number]

    @property
    def category(self):
        return 'business' if 2 <= self._number <= 6 else 'weekend'

    @property
    def number(self):
        return self._number

    @number.setter
    def number(self, value):
        if 1 <= value <= 7:
            self._number = value
        else:
            raise ValueError(self.ERROR_INVALID_NUMBER)


class WeekdayInterface:
    def __init__(self):
        self._weekday = Weekday()

    def request_value(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self._weekday = Weekday(int(input('Type the number of the day on the week (ex: 1 - Sunday):')))
                self.show()
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)

    def show(self):
        print(f'The day {self._weekday.number} is {self._weekday.name.lower()}')
        print(f'{self._weekday.name} is a {self._weekday.category.lower()} day.')


WeekdayInterface().request_value()
```

Comment: I'm not in love with the "Weekday" name. I wouldn't normally call Saturday a weekday. It's a day of the week, but not a weekday.

Comment: Agreed, `DayOfWeek` or just `Day` might have been better.